# How to count number of li using jquery

Tags: jquery

How do i get number of li's using jquery inside tricker

```
<ul id="ticker>

        <li>
            <h4><a href=" "="">LG G3 smartphone will launch globally on 27 May


        <li>
            <h4><a href="">Apple iWatch enters production, to launch in second half of 2014</a></h4>
            </li>

        <li>
            <h4><a href="">Apple patent reveals plans for iWatch wearable</a></h4>
            </li>

    </ul>
```

I tried below but it always return 0

```
  var newsitems = $("#ticker li h4 a").hide().size();
```

Comment: Fix it: `<ul id="ticker>` missing last `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var newsitems = $("#ticker li").length;` will give you the count

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have things like `<a href=" "="">` and `<ul id="ticker>`. Fix that.

Comment: As you can see, when your HTML is correct, it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Km7tx/

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing `"` after the id `ticker` in your HTML. Fix your HTML, and the javascript works just fine.

You should also use `.length` instead of `.size()` because as pointed out below, `size()` is deprecated.